# Template argument deduction error

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
void foo(int i)
{
  //nothing inside
}

int main()
{
   foo(5); //fails
   foo<int>(5); //works
}
```

Why does foo(5) fail but foo< int >(5) work?

Comment: What type T do you think the template should be instantiated with? In the case of template parameters, just because it's not used doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: Same reason why `foo<int>();` wouldn't work.

Comment: @litb:  I tried upvoting your deleted response. :)

Comment: Try explaining why you *think* it *should* work, then we can correct your thinking..

Answer (score 4):

You perhaps wanted to write

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T i)          // note the type of i
{
  //nothing inside
}
```

---

**Update**

Following is complete code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
void foo( T i ) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " called with " << i << "\n";
}

int main() {
    foo( 5 );
    foo<int>( 7 );
}
```

and output:

```
void foo(T) [with T = int] called with 5
void foo(T) [with T = int] called with 7
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not know what is T.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function as a template function, then you need to define what type you are going to use (even though your function does not use the template type)

So you need to tell the compiler what type T is.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does foo(5) fail but foo< int >(5) work?

Because there is no way for the compiler to determine what `T` is [from `foo(5)`] .

You can only leave template arguments of the end, not the beginning or middle:

For example:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
void foo(T t) 
{
}
template<typename T, typename U> 
void bar(U u) 
{
}

int main() 
{
    foo<int>(5);      // Error!! Compiler cannot decide what `U` is
    foo<int, int>(5); // Works!!

    bar<int>(5);      // Works!! `U` deduced from `5` (int)
    bar<int, int>(5); // Works!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd have something like this:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T i) { }
```

Then, when you pass an `int` as the parameter, the compiler can deduce that `T` must be `int`. Since your code doesn't use `T` anywhere,  the compiler has nothing to go on to deduce what it might be.